# I want to console.log Hello, with the username to be mentioned but it now working in the console.log

Tags: javascript

I want to console.log Hello, with the username to be mentioned but it now working in the console.log
[image]

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 2):

You should use *back-ticks*: `` instead of *double quotations*: "", it should be:

```
  console.log(`Hello, ${username}`);
```